# Combining between two csproj files safely

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, csproj

I have two very long and detailed .csproj files.
I want to combine them into one.

I used text comparer but the items are not in the same order 
and it's hard to isolate differences.

How would you recommend to combine them?
(they have compile, include, post build and after build events)

**edit:**
 I want to merge 2 unrelated projects with some common dependencies

Comment: Do you want to _sync_ 2 versions or _merge_ 2 unrelated projects?

Comment: The csproj files are xml.  You can build a program that will pull both of them into memory, and compare the values of the nodes and output the combined contents.

Comment: @Henk Holterman I want to merge 2 unrelated projects with some common dependencies.

Comment: @Kevin, Elad: They actually are MsBuild files. That might help when looking for tools.

Comment: Its not hard...Unless were talking hundreds of files, I don't see the problem, of course this would take 1/3 the time if you just created a new solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do most of this in Visual Studio. You can either drag the files you need from one project to the other, or you can copy all the files from one project folder to the other in the file system and turn on "show all files" in the solution explorer to show which need to be added. You will then need to align the namespaces. The Class View window can help identify types which do not fall inside the right namespace. A refactoring tool like Resharper can also help fix up the namespaces.

If you have explicit pre or post build events in each project, I would use the VS GUI to show these and manually combine. If you have custom build targets/tasks in the files, I would isolate these in a good text/XML editor and manually union them as required.

The other thing you will have to do is to add references to the final project which it did not originally require but were required by the other project. It should be quite quick to identify which references need to be added, by attempting compilation and inspecting any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the files from project 1 into the project 2 folder. Then turn on "Show all files" so you can see the files that aren't in the project. Then right-click each file and choose "Include in project".

Comment: To add on to this, you could open up the project files as XML and copy the references from the source to the target.